Function output is comma separated string instead of columns
Here is my function:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tsc_out_only(areaid_array character varying[], d_date date, start_time__ timestamp without time zone, end_time__ timestamp without time zone)
 RETURNS TABLE(imei___ character varying, area_id_ uuid, uc_name_ character varying, cluster__id_ text, campaign__date_ date, individual_dept_time_ interval, departure__status_ text, num_of_dept_ bigint, final_dep_check_ interval)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    i integer := 1;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..array_length(areaid_array, 1) LOOP
    
    RETURN QUERY


 with  
 
 
 total_imei as 
    (
                select 
                  assets."IMEI" as imei, caa."campaignScopeAreaID" as uc_id 
                from 
                  campaign_staff staff 
                  left join campaign_staff_assets csa on csa."campaignStaffID" = staff."ID" and csa."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_staff_assets cs2 where cs2."campaignStaffID"= csa."campaignStaffID" and cs2.date<=d_date::date)
                  left join campaign_area_assets caa on caa."assetID" = csa."assetID" 
                  and caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = csa."campaignScopeID" 
                  left join assets assets on assets."ID" = caa."assetID" 
                  left join staff_type staff_type ON staff_type."ID" = staff."staffTypeID"
                  left join campaign_asset_status cas  on cas."campaignStaffID" = staff."ID" and cas."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_asset_status cas2 where cas2."campaignStaffID"= cas."campaignStaffID" and cas2.date<=d_date::date)
                  left join campaign_scope cs on cs."areaID" = caa."campaignScopeAreaID"
                  
                  where 
                  
                  caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = areaid_array[i]::uuid and
                  assets."IMEI" is not null 
                  and staff_type."ID" = 'acf0cc70-7c92-474d-82af-f37494f94c09' -- Team ID
                  and (cas.status is null or cas.status  <> 'DeployedWoPhone')
                  and d_date::date between cs."campaignStartDate" and cs."catchupEndDate"
                  --and caa."campaignScopeAreaID"='2337a34b-5f76-4854-b39a-ec1b3deddc91'--TESTING
                  
              )    
    
 ,
 
 orig_dataset as not materialized (

    select caa."campaignScopeAreaID"  as uc_id , cr.imei ,cr."geoJson" as points_geom  , 
    
    lead(cr."geoJson") over (partition by cr.imei order by cr."generatedAt") as leading_points,
    LEAD(cr."geoJson", 2) OVER (PARTITION BY cr.imei ORDER BY cr."generatedAt") AS leading_points_2,
    LEAD(cr."geoJson", 3) OVER (PARTITION BY cr.imei ORDER BY cr."generatedAt") AS leading_points_3,
    LEAD(cr."geoJson", 4) OVER (PARTITION BY cr.imei ORDER BY cr."generatedAt") AS leading_points_4,
    LEAD(cr."geoJson", 5) OVER (PARTITION BY cr.imei ORDER BY cr."generatedAt") AS leading_points_5,
    
 
    cr."generatedAt"+interval '5 hours'  as time_created
    
    from campaign_pings cr 
    
    left join assets a on a."IMEI"  = cr.imei 
    left join campaign_area_assets caa on a."ID"  = caa."assetID"  
    
    where 
    
    
    
    cr.imei in (select imei from total_imei) 
    
    and 
    
    cr."generatedAt" + interval '5 hours' between start_time__ and end_time__
    
    
    --and caa."campaignScopeAreaID"='2337a34b-5f76-4854-b39a-ec1b3deddc91'--TESTING
   -- and caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = areaid_array[i]::uuid
    
    
    --and io.imei is not null 
    )
    ,
    
    
    cluster_groups as not materialized (
    select areaid , id as cluster_id, geojson  as cluster_centroid  from predict_tsc tsc  
    where approved = 'Approved' and date::date=d_date
    
    and 
    --areaid ='2337a34b-5f76-4854-b39a-ec1b3deddc91'--TESTING
    areaid::uuid = areaid_array[i]::uuid
    )
    
    
    
    
 
    
    ,
    dept_cluster_raw as (
    
    SELECT 
           routes.uc_id ,
           cg.cluster_id ,
           cg.cluster_centroid ,
           routes.imei ,    
           routes.time_created::date as campaign_date,
           
           count(routes.time_created) as num_of_dept,
           
           min(routes.time_created) as min_per_imei_cluster,
           
           max(routes.time_created) as final_dep_check
    FROM cluster_groups as cg
    
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    
      SELECT routes.time_created,routes.imei, routes.uc_id
      
      FROM orig_dataset as routes
      
      where 
     
      --routes.time_created between start_time__ and end_time__
    
      --and
    (  
      
   ST_DWithin(
  st_transform(routes.points_geom, 4326)::geography,
  st_transform(ST_SetSRID(cg.cluster_centroid, 4326), 4326)::geography,
  100
)
AND NOT ST_DWithin(
  st_transform(leading_points, 4326)::geography,
  st_transform(ST_SetSRID(cg.cluster_centroid, 4326), 4326)::geography,
  100
)
AND NOT ST_DWithin(
  st_transform(leading_points_2, 4326)::geography,
  st_transform(ST_SetSRID(cg.cluster_centroid, 4326), 4326)::geography,
  100
)
AND NOT ST_DWithin(
  st_transform(leading_points_2, 4326)::geography,
  st_transform(leading_points, 4326)::geography,
  10
)
AND NOT ST_DWithin(
  st_transform(leading_points_3, 4326)::geography,
  st_transform(ST_SetSRID(cg.cluster_centroid, 4326), 4326)::geography,
  100
)
AND NOT ST_DWithin(
  st_transform(leading_points_3, 4326)::geography,
  st_transform(leading_points_2, 4326)::geography,
  10
)
AND NOT ST_DWithin(
  st_transform(leading_points_4, 4326)::geography,
  st_transform(ST_SetSRID(cg.cluster_centroid, 4326), 4326)::geography,
  100
)
AND NOT ST_DWithin(
  st_transform(leading_points_4, 4326)::geography,
  st_transform(leading_points_3, 4326)::geography,
  10
)
AND NOT ST_DWithin(
  st_transform(leading_points_5, 4326)::geography,
  st_transform(ST_SetSRID(cg.cluster_centroid, 4326), 4326)::geography,
  100
)
AND NOT ST_DWithin(
  st_transform(leading_points_5, 4326)::geography,
  st_transform(leading_points_4, 4326)::geography,
  10
)
      
      )
      
      
      ) routes --where routes.uc_id=cg.areaid::uuid
    
    group by 1,2,3,4,5
    
    )
    ,
    
    dept_master_data as 
    (
    select imei,uc_id,cluster_id,campaign_date,min_per_imei_cluster as individual_dept_time, 
    num_of_dept,final_dep_check from dept_cluster_raw  
    )
    
    ,
     
    dept_labelled as 
    (
    select imei,uc_id,cluster_id,campaign_date, date_trunc('seconds', individual_dept_time::time) as individual_dept_time ,   
    case when individual_dept_time is not null
    then 'Dept_time_exists' 
    else 'No_dept_found' 
    end as dept_status,
    num_of_dept,
    final_dep_check
    from dept_master_data 
    )
    
    
    
    ,
    
    result_set as 
    
    (
    select dl.*  
    from dept_labelled dl 

    /*full outer join arrival_labelled al
    on dl.imei=al.imei 
    and dl.uc_id=al.uc_id 
    and dl.cluster_id=al.cluster_id 
    and dl.campaign_date = al.campaign_date */
    order by dl.uc_id,dl.campaign_date 
    )
    
    ,
    final_times as
    (
    select * from result_set  
    )
    ,
    
    
    final_times_ranked as (
    select imei ,uc_id as uc_id,cluster_id as cluster_id,campaign_date as campaign_date,individual_dept_time,dept_status,num_of_dept,final_dep_check
  
      
    
    from final_times)
    ,
    
    final_times_ranked_2 as (
    select *--, dense_rank() over (partition by imei order by individual_dept_time,cluster_id) as ranked_imei
    from final_times_ranked)
    
    
  
    ,
    
    combined as (
    select * from final_times_ranked_2 --where ranked_imei<=1 
    )
    ,
    
    display_result as ( 
    select combined.*,total_imei.imei as binded_imei_,total_imei.uc_id as uc_id_binded
    from combined
    right join total_imei
    on total_imei.imei=combined.imei 
    )
    
    
    ,
    naming_uc as 
    (
    select display_result.*, a.name as uc_name  
    from display_result left join area a on a."ID" = display_result.uc_id_binded 
    )
    ,
    answer as (
    select *,coalesce (dept_status,'No_dept_found') as Departure_status_  from naming_uc 
    --order by uc_id,cluster_id 
    )
    ,
    joined as (
    select *,d_date::date as campaign_date_binded  from answer 
    where uc_id_binded in (select tsc.areaid::uuid as uc_id_imported  from predict_tsc tsc) 
    ),
    
    joined_2 as (
    select coalesce (imei,binded_imei_) as imei, coalesce(uc_id,uc_id_binded) as uc_id, cluster_id, coalesce (campaign_date,campaign_date_binded) as campaign_date,
    individual_dept_time,departure_status_,num_of_dept,final_dep_check  
    from joined 
    ),
    
    show_this as (
    select joined_2.imei,joined_2.uc_id, a.name as uc_name, joined_2.cluster_id::text,joined_2.campaign_date,individual_dept_time,departure_status_,num_of_dept,date_trunc('seconds',final_dep_check::time) as final_dep_check
    
    
    
    --to_char(to_timestamp((tcr.num_of_pings_in_tsc::numeric/60) * 60), 'MI:SS') as time_in_tsc
    
    from joined_2 
    left join area a  on a."ID" = joined_2.uc_id 
    
    --left join total_cluster_raw tcr on tcr.imei =joined_2.imei
    --and tcr.uc_id = joined_2.uc_id 
    --and tcr.cluster_id=joined_2.cluster_id 
    --and tcr.campaign_date =joined_2.campaign_date 
    
    order by uc_id,cluster_id
    )
    ,
    remainder_1 as ( 
     
    select imei from total_imei
    
    except 
    
    (select imei from show_this
    
    except
    --bad results
    (select imei from show_this
    where departure_status_ = 'No_dept_found'
    ))
    
    )
    
    ,
    
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    script_1_and_2_combo_results as (
    
    (select * from show_this
    except
    select * from show_this
    where Departure_status_ = 'No_dept_found'
    )
    
    --union 
    --select * from renaming_TSC_with_count   
    )
    
      
    ,
    
    final_master_results as (
    select * from script_1_and_2_combo_results 
    
    union
    
    ------------
    select * from show_this
    where (Departure_status_ = 'No_dept_found'
    
    and 
    imei not in (select imei from script_1_and_2_combo_results))
    ---------------
    )
    
    ,
    final_master_results_formatted as 
    (
    select * from final_master_results 
    union
    
    (select imei, uc_id,uc.name as uc_name, null as cluster_id, d_date::date as campaign_date, null as individual_dept_time,
     'No_dept_found' as departure_status_, null as num_of_dept,null as final_dep_check 
    
    --null as time_in_tsc 
    from total_imei 
    left join area  uc on uc."ID" = total_imei.uc_id 
    where imei not in (select imei from final_master_results )
    
    )
    )
    
  
    
    
    select * from final_master_results_formatted;
    
    END LOOP;
END
$function$
;


The problem is that instead of columns as specified in the function definition, I am getting comma separated values in each row. How do I change this, so that I have values in columns. The problem is that instead of columns as specified in the function definition, I am getting comma separated values in each row. How do I change this, so that I have values in columns.

"I am getting comma separated values in each row" - where? In what query?

@Bergi when I run this function call - select tsc_out_only(array['7e555edb-f93f-49af-a9ab-493873ff5487'], '2024-04-29','2024-04-29 06:00:00','2024-04-29 18:00:00')


when I run this function call, I am getting comma separated values in each row
select tsc_out_only(array['7e555edb-f93f-49af-a9ab-493873ff5487'], '2024-04-29','2024-04-29 06:00:00','2024-04-29 18:00:00')


Yes, that selects one column (named tsc_out_only) whose type is your record (that is the return type declared by the function). It's not a comma-separated string, it's just a row literal that you'll get shown as text, depending on your client. Regardless, if you actually want multiple columns, you need to use
select * from tsc_out_only(array['7e555edb-f93f-49af-a9ab-493873ff5487'], '2024-04-29','2024-04-29 06:00:00','2024-04-29 18:00:00')

or
select tsc_out_only(array['7e555edb-f93f-49af-a9ab-493873ff5487'], '2024-04-29','2024-04-29 06:00:00','2024-04-29 18:00:00').*

